# Unable to run Android Emulator for connected tests in jenkins

Tags: android, ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to run connectedtests from Jenkins, and I am unable to load emulator from Jenkins server(ubuntu 18 VM) but with -nowindow tag I am able to load emulator.

The following error occurred:

```
Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

With debug enabled for qt plugin I was able to see the detailed errors:

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" ... ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64" ... ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64-headless" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64-headless'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel-headless" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel-headless'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386-headless" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386-headless'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless'" 
         not a plugin ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins/platforms" ... ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb") ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/platforms" ... ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Debug: loaded library "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" ((null):0, (null))


No protocol specified
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: could not connect to display :0 ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))
```

Note: I have also added environment variables for QT but nothing worked.